# SQL - To subquery or not to subquery?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm having trouble filling my database with plenty of records to do a speed test. Can anybody tell me which query should be faster when dealing with millions of records? I like Tomas' query the most, but won't the DISTINCT be slowing it down a lot when dealing with a bigger table?

I am surprised to see that my subquery does not slow things down as much as I thought it would.

:: Mine. Producing 22 rows in 00.0640419 > 00.1030255 seconds.

```
SELECT
    [planning].[id] as planningId,
    [planning].[type] as planningType,
    [planning].[from] as planningFrom,
    [planning].[till] as planningTill,
    [worker].[intId] as workerId,
    [worker].[name] as workerName,
    [site].[intId] as siteId,
    [site].[name] as siteName
FROM
    [worker]
    LEFT JOIN [planning] ON [planning].[workerId] = [worker].[intId] AND [planning].[companyId] = [worker].[companyId]
    LEFT JOIN [site] ON [planning].[siteId] = [site].[intId] AND [planning].[companyId] = [site].[companyId]
WHERE 
    [worker].[companyId] = 2
    AND ( [planning].[id] IS NULL  OR  ( [planning].[from] <= '2014-04-30' AND [planning].[till] >= '2014-04-01') )
    AND ([worker].[intId] IN (
        SELECT 
          [worker].[intId] 
        FROM 
          [planning]
          INNER JOIN [worker] ON [planning].[workerId] = [worker].[intId] AND [planning].[companyId] = [worker].[companyId]
        WHERE
          [worker].[companyId] = 2
          AND ([planning].[type] = 'absent' OR ([planning].[siteId] IN ('7710122')))
      ) OR [worker].[intId] IN ('7701260')
  )
```

:: Sirko. Producing 22 rows in 00.0684108 > 00.0955292 seconds.

```
SELECT
    [planning].[id] as planningId,
    [planning].[type] as planningType,
    [planning].[from] as planningFrom,
    [planning].[till] as planningTill,
    [worker].[intId] as workerId,
    [worker].[name] as workerName,
    [site].[intId] as siteId,
    [site].[name] as siteName
FROM
    [worker]
    LEFT JOIN [planning] ON [planning].[workerId] = [worker].[intId] AND [planning].[companyId] = [worker].[companyId]
    LEFT JOIN [site] ON [planning].[siteId] = [site].[intId] AND [planning].[companyId] = [site].[companyId]
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT
                    [worker].[intId] 
                FROM 
                    [planning]
                    LEFT JOIN [worker] ON [planning].[workerId] = [worker].[intId] AND [planning].[companyId] = [worker].[companyId]
                WHERE
                    [worker].[companyId] = 2
                    AND ([planning].[type] = 'absent' OR ([planning].[type] = 'site' AND [planning].[siteId] IN ('7710122')))
               ) AS filter ON filter.[intId] = [worker].[intId]
WHERE 
    [worker].[companyId] = 2
    AND ( ( [planning].[from] <= '2014-04-30' AND [planning].[till] >= '2014-04-01') OR [worker].[intId] IN ('7701260') )
```

:: Tomas Pastircak. Producing 22 rows in 00.0674178 > 00.0850567 seconds.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    [planning].[id] as planningId,
    [planning].[type] as planningType,
    [planning].[from] as planningFrom,
    [planning].[till] as planningTill,
    [worker].[intId] as workerId,
    [worker].[name] as workerName,
    [site].[intId] as siteId,
    [site].[name] as siteName
FROM
    [worker]
    LEFT JOIN [planning] ON [planning].[workerId] = [worker].[intId] AND [planning].[companyId] = [worker].[companyId]
    LEFT JOIN [site] ON [planning].[siteId] = [site].[intId] AND [planning].[companyId] = [site].[companyId]
    LEFT JOIN [planning] p2 ON p2.[workerId] = [worker].[intId] AND p2.[companyId] = [worker].[companyId]
WHERE 
    [worker].[companyId] = 2
        AND ( [planning].[id] IS NULL  OR  ( [planning].[from] <= '2014-04-30' AND [planning].[till] >= '2014-04-01') )
    AND (p2.[type] = 'absent' OR p2.[siteId] IN ('7710122') OR [worker].[intId] IN ('7701260'))
```

Comment: Another join would do the trick.

Comment: temp table ? store procedure ? why not ? it could be helpfull if you run this query many times.Also these queries show that maybe something is not good in the table design

Comment: @Sirko Another join might be what i need.. but how? I need to return every planning (= sites) of a user. Not just the one I've selected.

Comment: if you could provide some example data and the result data (the data that u desire), some1 probably could help u optimize the querry.

Comment: This looks like a problem where you may need to balance performance and readability for future maintenance. When I need to do this I try to separate the sub-queries (Like the worker Id's) into a separate query using a table variable or CTE.  (DECLARE @WorkerIds Table (Id INT).  Insert into @WorkerId(Id) (SELECT ..Complex sub query).   The main query is then simplified with WorkerId IN (SELECT Id FROM @WorkerIds).  This is much more readable for future edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why couldn't you just add it to the WHERE conditions, without all the subquery stuff? It seems to return the same data...

```
SELECT
...
FROM
...
LEFT JOIN [planning] p2 ON p2.[workerId] = [worker].[intId] AND p2.[companyId] = [worker].[companyId]

WHERE 
    [worker].[companyId] = 2
    AND ( [planning].[id] IS NULL  OR  ( [planning].[from] <= '2014-04-30' AND [planning].[till] >= '2014-04-01') )
    AND (p2.[type] = 'absent' OR (p2.[type] = 'site' AND p2.[siteId] IN ('7710122'))
```

Comment: This way I would only be returning the records showing the selected planning. I need to return all of the records of the user that has an activity planned in the same period as the selected site.

Comment: @TieleDeclercq Improved, try now

Comment: This kinda works.. but it returns way to many records (doubles)! My original query returns a correct 21 rows in 00.0916370 seconds. This query returns 140 rows in 00.1273364 seconds. When grouping the results together it would be even slower no?

Comment: @TieleDeclercq Changing `SELECT` to `SELECT DISTINCT` at the beginning should help. However, I think the performance of this would be equal or close to equal to your query... I understood this should be a readability improvement, I can't think of any good execution time improvement, that 0.03s is probably caused by higher amount of results.

Comment: There may not be a 'best' solution but I went for Tomas's query because it is without an extra subquery and therefor the most 'simple-looking'.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly familiar with T-SQL syntax, but something like the following should work:

```
SELECT
    [planning].[id] as planningId,
    [planning].[type] as planningType,
    [planning].[from] as planningFrom,
    [planning].[till] as planningTill,
    [planning].[busyMon] as busyMon,
    [planning].[busyTue] as busyTue,
    [planning].[busyWed] as busyWed,
    [planning].[busyThu] as busyThu,
    [planning].[busyFri] as busyFri,
    [planning].[busySat] as busySat,
    [planning].[busySun] as busySun,
    [planning].[busyHolidays] as busyHolidays,
    [worker].[intId] as workerId,
    [worker].[name] as workerName,
    [worker].[partner] as workerPartner,
    [site].[intId] as siteId,
    [site].[name] as siteName
FROM
    [worker]
    LEFT JOIN [planning] ON [planning].[workerId] = [worker].[intId] AND [planning].[companyId] = [worker].[companyId]
    LEFT JOIN [site] ON [planning].[siteId] = [site].[intId] AND [planning].[companyId] = [site].[companyId]
    LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT
                    [worker].[intId] 
                FROM 
                    [planning]
                    LEFT JOIN [worker] ON [planning].[workerId] = [worker].[intId] AND [planning].[companyId] = [worker].[companyId]
                WHERE
                    [worker].[companyId] = 2
                    AND ([planning].[type] = 'absent' OR ([planning].[type] = 'site' AND [planning].[siteId] IN ('7710122','123456')))
               ) AS filter ON filter.[intId] = [worker].[intId] OR [worker].[intId] IN ('987654','654321')
WHERE 
    [worker].[companyId] = 2
      AND ( [planning].[id] IS NULL  OR  ( [planning].[from] <= '2014-04-30' AND [planning].[till] >= '2014-04-01') )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a full answer, but my point is not well made in a comment so I'll put it here.

Your big subquery seems wrong to me to start with:

```
SELECT worker.intId 
  FROM planning
       LEFT JOIN 
       worker ON planning.workerId = worker.intId 
             AND planning.companyId = worker.companyId
 WHERE worker.companyId = 2
   AND (   planning.type = 'absent' 
        OR (    planning.type = 'site' 
            AND planning.siteId IN ('7710122','123456')
           )
       )
```

The LEFT JOIN from planning to worker combined with worker.companyId = 2 will result in an INNER JOIN.

Can you clarify in words what you are trying to accomplish with the subquery?

Comment: True. That's due to a sloppy copy/paste.

Comment: The subquery should fetch the workerId's that are booked in a period of time. The main query then fetches all of the workers with (or without if there aren't any) his booked 'placed to be'.

Comment: Please edit you post to correct any copy/paste errors. Also, this will be much easier to ready of you remove the unnecessary square brackets `[` and `]` and alias the tables in you FROM using those alias in the SELECT.